# Unable to read the credential file specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I was able to deploy the site locally after adding the `putenv` in my **wp-config.php** file. However when I run `gcloud app deploy`, I get the error in the domain.

According to https://wordpress.org/plugins/gcs/#installation I have placed my json file in Dropbox, see screenshot below. Where should the right place be?

[Screenshot showing `putenv` in **wp-config.php**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBV5k.png)

See the error I get after deploying [Dosbranding](https://dosbranding.co.ke)

Answer (score 2):

i have a similiar problem with php 7.2. php can't read enviroment vars, this must be declared into the **etc/apache2/envars**
add this lines to this file, solved my problem

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/var/www/html/myjson.json
export FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=/var/www/html/myjson.json
```

Answer (score 0):

It says

> Upload the json key file to the hosting server. Don’t put it in a
>   public serving area.

that means you have to deploy it with your project.

Your dropbox folder is local to your computer hence it is visible when you run local dev instance.

You **probably** should place the json in the same location as your wp-config.php and than set the env to:

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=dosbrandingke-f191a195723d.json');

Comment: I tried that but the plugin is still not working. See the new screenshot above. i.stack.imgur.com/SQbsc.png